# Androd app shortcuts intent flags

Tags: android, activity

Работаю над добавлением шорткатов в приложение, пробую использовать для них реализованный функционал для диплинков. В приложении есть функциональность авторизации пользователей, поэтому если юзер зашел по диплинку/шорткату в приложение и при этом сессия пользователя не открыта, то приложение должно сначала перейти на экран авторизации. Для этого в *ApplinkActivity*, отвечающей за прием диплинов/шорткатов - реализована логика типа:

```
if (isTaskRoot) {
    startActivity(StartupActivity.createIntent(this))
}
```

Получается, если *ApplinkActivity* первая в стеке, то должна произойти навигация на активити авторизации. Диплинки работают как положено, но с шорткатами проблема. Я использую статические шорткаты и задаю интент в **xml**. Проблема в том, что по нажатию на шорткат открывается *ApplinkActivity* всегда в качестве **root** активити. Судя по всему интент из шортката по умолчанию задан с флагами типа **FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK** и **FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK**. Есть ли возможность каким то образом изменить это поведение? Или проблема вообще в другом?
Пример статического шортката:

```
<shortcut
    android:shortcutId="shortcut_open_smth"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_open_smth_shortcut"
    android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/shortcut_open_smth_title">

    <intent
        android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
        android:targetPackage="com.shortcutapp"
        android:targetClass="com.shortcutapp.activities.applink.ApplinkActivity"
        android:data="shortcutapp.com/applink/open_smth" />

</shortcut>
```

Comment: 1 - Открывать не эту активити и сделать переход на эту 2 - Сделать single активити. Вы можете в поле android:action=" дать интенту уникальное имя. И по этому имени ловить интент в системе

Comment: Например android:action="com.shortcutapp.activities.applink,applink.BUS"